# problem loading page,connection timed out

Tags: onion-services

When i go to hidden wiki 95 percent of the websites will not open. I get a message that connection is timed out because the site took to long to respond I am new to this and I do not know what to try to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most onion sites are run by amateurs and are thus going down temporarily/permanently all the time. This can be seemingly exacerbated by indexes not removing links that have been down for a significant length of time.

If you can access "big" onion services such as Facebook's (https://facebookcorewwwi.onion) or DuckDuckGo's (http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/), then you're very likely trying to access onion services that are down. There's probably nothing wrong with your configuration.